# Best way to copy site collections

Tags: site-collection, spsite, guid

I am looking in to copying a whole SP 2013 collection to a new one.
(target URL could be in the same server or farm, though unlikely)
I want to mention that, this is meant to be a 'copy machine' to run again and again, not only once.

By using C# code and PowerShell commands, with the Copy-SPSite command to be precise,
I am able to copy the hole site collection to a new location.

I have noticed however that the GUIDs of the lists, etc in the target site collection
are the same as those in of the original site. The site collection GUID changes though.

I would like to ask if this, having the same GUIDs in the lists, could create future problems and if someone could share a better approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly welcome to SharePoint StackExchange.

The GUIDs for Lists and Libraries can be identical on several sites as the site GUID is used in building up the access paths in the background.

In short this should not impose a problem, infact it can actually be a benefit in some scenarios and I have from time to time given list types a static GUID in the list definition.

Hope this helps.